# WPF DataGrid Buttons only work when debugging inside VS

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, event-handling, wpfdatagrid

Hi I'm using WPF to make a simple application, it has the following inside it:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="StreetViewGrid" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StreetViewRecords}}" Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- ... -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="StreetEditRecordButton" Content="Edit" Margin="5" Click="StreetEditRecordButton_Click" />
                        <Button x:Name="StreetDeleteRecordButton" Content="Delete" Margin="5" Click="StreetDeleteRecordButton_Click" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When running in VS (via F5) these buttons work beautifully (I.E: they open up a MessageBox or some other desired dialog).
However, if I run the built app from either the bin folders OR even after a One-Click publish these events never seen to get triggered, nothing happens not even an error.
This is the case in both Debug and Release builds.

Has anyone else has this issue? Am I doing the edit and delete buttons wrong?

**Edit:** I have other buttons on the window which are placed statically on the window and they all work fine, it appears to be just these 2 "dynamic" buttons.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Have you tried changing staticResource to DynamicResource.  and second thing please try to catch the exception in Dispatcher Unhandled Exception

Comment: Changing to DynamicResource caused XAML Parser errors and wrapping the code in try...catch seems pointless as the application doesn't crash it just doesn't trigger the click events on these 2 edit and delete buttons. But, as i say it only EVER works when running in debug mode via VS2012. Even using CTRL+F5 recreated the issue so not sure what's going on